# Why use the JavaScript postfix increment/decrement operators?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning ES6 at [JavaScript.info](https://javascript.info/operators#increment-decrement), and it says about the increment/decrement operators:

> The prefix form returns the new value while the postfix form returns the old value (prior to increment/decrement)...
>
> If we’d like to increase a value and immediately use the result of the operator, we need the prefix form...
>
> **If we’d like to increment a value but use its previous value, we need the postfix form.**

But I'm confused as to when it would ever be necessary to use the previous value of a variable after it's been incremented? Would it be safe to assume that wherever it is, these are edgecases and the prefix form `++counter` should almost always be preferred, or is there actually a good reason that the postfix `counter++` form is more commonly seen out in the wild?

Comment: the postfix and prefix increment/decrement operators were a part of the language before ES6

Comment: FWIW, those operators have existed since forever, he are not new to ES6. And the exists in other languages as well.

Comment: It's up to you, you should use the one you need for the case you have

Comment: Edited accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I'm confused as to when it would ever be necessary to use the previous value of a variable after it's been incremented?

The idea is to (1) use the previous value, and then (2) increment the variable. For example, you might use it like this:

```js
let index = 0;

const obj1 = { id: index++ };
const obj2 = { id: index++ };

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

Sometimes, that's what you need. Other times, you might want to extract the value *after* the increment is done, eg:

```js
let highestIndexSoFar = 0;

const obj1 = { id: ++highestIndexSoFar };
const obj2 = { id: ++highestIndexSoFar };

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(highestIndexSoFar);
```

It depends on the situation. Both have their place.

Though, another option is to avoid them and instead increment only as a standalone statement, outside of an expression context - some may find that to be more readable instead:

```js
let highestIndexSoFar = 0;

highestIndexSoFar++;
const obj1 = { id: highestIndexSoFar };
highestIndexSoFar++;
const obj2 = { id: highestIndexSoFar };

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(highestIndexSoFar);
```

Comment: To clarify, when incrementing as a standalone statement, don't the usual rules about the prefix and postfix operators apply?

Comment: They do, but the rules don't matter, because the resulting expression isn't being used; all that it does is increment the variable. Whether one uses postfix or prefix has no effect in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be safe to assume that wherever it is, these are edgecases
> and the prefix form ++counter should almost always be preferred, or is
> there actually a good reason that the postfix counter++ form is more
> commonly seen out in the wild?

You would find more pre decrement usage out in the wild than post increment **but** adding to provided answer above, It is generally a better idea not to use pre/post increment/decrement if possible and use shorthand plus/minus operators like so:

`counter += 1` ;
`counter -= 1`

The idea being that it's just more developer friendly when it comes to refactoring and also it prevents you from odd looking code. I have seen this a lot that people use double `x++` instead of `x += 2` which is arguably more cleaner way of coding.